# Backgroundworker doesn't find a symbol

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, smart-device-framework

Please I cant find a symbol BackgroundWorker in my application Net 3.5 (Smart device). I find it just in WPF.

I tried to download but I did not find a link

```
using System.ComponentModel;
<p style="red">BackgroundWorker</p> 
myWorker = new <p style="red">BackgroundWorker</p>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common option is to use [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) instead of a BackgroundWorker, although there are other options available as well.

You can also use [Microsoft .NET Compact Framework Background Processing Techniques](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446488.aspx) for Performing background processing has many implications and requires very careful design. This paper offers some suggestions for making the best use of background processing and introduces many of the issues that must be addressed.

Comment: thank you  but I downloaded the dll from this URL :http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/backgroundworker-for-cf-10.aspx